# Rails How to append comments to a collection of microposts without page reload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partial

I've two models; Micropost and Comment.
Micropost has many comments and Comment belongs to Micropost.

First of all. There's a StaticPagesController which holds my home action

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
    if logged_in?
      @micropost = current_user.microposts.build
      @feed_items = current_user.microposts.paginate(page: params[:page])
    end
  end
(..)
```

`home.html.erb` renders a feed

```
= render 'shared/feed'
```

`_feed.html.haml` renders feed_items

```
- if @feed_items.any?
  %ol.microposts
    = render @feed_items
  = will_paginate @feed_items
```

which renders `_micropost.html.haml`

```
%li
  %div.comments{data: { mid: "#{micropost.id}"}}
    %div.comment_container{:id => "comments_for_#{micropost.id}"}
      %ul
        - comments = micropost.comments
        - comments.each do |comment|
          %li 
            %a{:href => user_path(comment.user), :class => "author"}
              = comment.user.name
            %span.comment_body= comment.body
            %span.comment_timestamp= "created " + time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at).to_s
    %div
      = form_for current_user.comments.build(:micropost_id => micropost.id), |
                                                   :remote => true do |f|
        = f.hidden_field :micropost_id
        = f.hidden_field :user_id
        = f.text_field :body, class: "form-control", placeholder: "What do you think?"
        = button_tag(type: 'submit', class: "btn btn-default") do
          %i.glyphicon.glyphicon-comment
          Comment
```

If a comment is submitted the create action is called

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :correct_user,   only: :destroy
  def create
    @micropost = Micropost.find(params[:comment][:micropost_id])
    @comments = @micropost.comments
    @comment = current_user.comments.build(comment_params)
    @comment.save
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
      format.html
    end
  private
    def comment_params
      params.require(:comment).permit(
        :id, :body, :user_id, :micropost_id)
    end
    def correct_user
      @comment = current_user.comments.find_by(id: params[:id])
      redirect_to root_url if @comment.nil?
    end
end
```

create.js.erb

```
var mid = $(".comment_container").parent(".comments").data('mid');
$("#comments_for_" + mid).html("<%= escape_javascript(render('comments/comment')) %>")
```

My goal is to add a new comment to its related micropost without reloading the whole page.

I've put micropost.id to the markup with `%div.comments{data: { mid: "#{micropost.id}"}}` and I tried to catch the micropost by its parent tag 
and finally (re-)render comments with a partial

but this returns always the same id and inserts every new comment at the same micropost.

How can I get knowledge of the micropost.id of a comment in `create.js.erb`?

_comment.html.erb

```
<ul>
  <% @comments.each do |comment| %>
    <li>
      <a class="author" href="<%= user_path(comment.user) %>">
        <%= comment.user.name %>
      </a>
      <span class="comment_body">
        <%= comment.body %>
      </span>
      <span class="comment_timestamp">
        <%= "created " + time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at).to_s %>
      </span>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Comment: Here is a good rails cast on passing data to JS.  http://railscasts.com/episodes/324-passing-data-to-javascript

Comment: cool thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try the following :

In your `create.js.erb` :

```
$("#comments_for_#{@comment.micropost_id}%>").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('comments/comment')) %>");
```

I suspect something is wrong with your jquery selectors, and you can achieve what you want more easily.

PS : You should not rely on instance variables in your partials. Instead, pass your instance vars to partials via locals. Otherwise your partials cannot be reused easily.

Comment: you're right `$("#comments_for_<%= @comment.micropost_id %>").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('comments/comment')) %>")
` works out, Thanks!